# Undefined index: aksi in PHP

Tags: php, post, get

Hi i'm getting an error as :Undefined index: aksi  my php code is:

```
    <?php
include"class_koneksi.php";
$db=new database();
$db->konek();

if(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi'] ==''){

    $daftar=$db->tampilData();
        echo"<table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Nama</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Pesan</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                <td>Hapus</td>
            </tr>";
    foreach($daftar as $data){
        echo" <tr>
                <td>".$data['id']."</td>
                <td>".$data['nama']."</td>
                <td>".$data['email']."</td>
                <td>".$data['pesan']."</td>
                <td><a href='?aksi=edit&id=$data[id]'>edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='?aksi=hapus_data&id=$data[id]'>Hapus</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo"</table> <br> <a href='?aksi=tambah'>TAMBAH</a>";


}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){ //line 31
    echo"<br>
    <form method=POST action='?aksi=tambah_data'>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan'></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    ";

}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='tambah_data'){ line 43
    $id=$_POST[id];
    $nama=$_POST['nama'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pesan=$_POST['pesan'];
    $db->tambahData($id,$nama,$email,$pesan);

}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='edit'){ //50
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    echo"<br>
        <form method=POST action='?aksi=update_data'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Id</td><td><input type=text name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama' value='".$db->bacaData(nama,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email' value='".$db->bacaData(email,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan' value='".$db->bacaData(pesan,$id)."'></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
            </table>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$db->bacaData(id,$id)."'>
        </form>
    ";

}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='update_data'){ //line 65
    $id=$_POST[id];
    $nama=$_POST['nama'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pesan=$_POST['pesan'];
    $db->updateData($id,$nama,$email,$pesan);

}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='hapus_data'){ //line 72
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $db->hapusData($id);
}

?>
```

can you tell me what problem from this code if(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi'] =='') but error Undefined index: aksi in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\lat1.php on line 31,43,50,65,72
is there any1 who cud help me out of this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `isset($_GET['aksi']) &&` in each of your `IF` statements as they are separate from each other. So using it in your first `IF` statement does not mean it is used in the rest of them.

For example:

```
}elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){ // line 31

}elseif(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='tambah_data'){ // line 43
```

Answer (score 0):

restructure your if's to something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['aksi']))
{
   if($_GET['aksi'])=='') ...

   if($_GET['aksi'])=='anyvalue') ...

   //..and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd best prefix your whole comparison once to see if there is a value. And possibly even combine it with a [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) in place of the various comparisons:

```
switch (isset($_GET["aksi"]) ? $_GET["aksi"] : "") {

     case "":
         ///
         break;

     case "tampah":
         ///

     case "tampah_data":
         ///

     case "edit":
         ///
```

That's briefer and often easier to follow.

Also investigate [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) strings for the two output blocks. Those allow to still use double quotes for HTML, but also interpolate variables or varexpressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)
```

Comment: Can you explain *why*? Any link to documentation?

Comment: I think it's a notice ,not error.so [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)